# Javascript - generate more than one random numbers without loop

Tags: javascript, random, vectorization

I want to generate an array with `n` random numbers (i.e. `n` calls to `Math.random()`). **I don't care about whether they are unique or not**.

Currently I'm using a loop:

```
let numbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    numbers.push(Math.random());
}
```

I'd just like to know if this can be vectorised - for example in other languages I'd expect something like `Math.random(n)` to produce an array of `n` random numbers. Or is a loop the way to go in Javascript?

cheers.

Comment: AFAIK this is a best way to produce and store n random numbers in a javascript array

Comment: Hmm, OK. Coming from a Matlab/R.python perspective and viewing JS as a similar high-level language, I just thought it might be vectorised in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way or another you will still get a loop somewhere underneath - even if there is any "vectorization" library for javascript, it will boil down to the loop.

Comment: OK, cheers. I come from a Matlab/R/python background, so my first instinct when I see a loop is still "vectorise!" - even though it boils down to a loop, a built-in vectorised method is usually much quicker than an explicit loop due to implementation. Just wondered if Javascript had that sort of mindset too.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, 'lazyness' may help.
If you are not certain you'll need all the n generated numbers. you'd better go with a lazy implementation using [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators) ...